# dont understand this xml line j2seproject

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, qsystemtrayicon

im beginer developer and im build some project, this project show error

BUILD FAILED

D:\ForJob\source-archive(ANT)\apertum-qsystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:951: The following error occurred while executing this line:

D:\ForJob\source-archive(ANT)\apertum-qsystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:291: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

```
<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
                    <src>
                        <dirset dir="@{gensrcdir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
                            <include name="*"/>
                        </dirset>
                    </src>
                    <classpath>
                        <path path="@{classpath}"/>
                    </classpath>
                    <compilerarg line="${endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg}"/>
                    <compilerarg line="${javac.profile.cmd.line.arg}"/>
                    <compilerarg line="${javac.compilerargs}"/>
                    <compilerarg value="-processorpath"/>
                    <compilerarg path="@{processorpath}:${empty.dir}"/>
                    <compilerarg line="${ap.processors.internal}"/>
                    <compilerarg line="${annotation.processing.processor.options}"/>
                    <compilerarg value="-s"/>
                    <compilerarg path="@{apgeneratedsrcdir}"/>
                    <compilerarg line="${ap.proc.none.internal}"/>
                    <customize/>
                </javac>


<target depends="init,deps-jar,-pre-pre-compile,-pre-compile, -copy-persistence-xml,-compile-depend" if="have.sources" name="-do-compile">
        <j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
        <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.reports.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes},${excludes}" includes="${includes}"/>
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes},${excludes}" includes="${includes}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
```

Comment: so ..; check the error, as that message suggests. Why do you start with J2SE if you are a beginner? besides the fact that you would need a solid knowledge of the basics beforehand, J2SE became obsolete about 13 years ago. Especially if learning, learn the latest version(s)

Comment: i modify old some open source

Comment: so ask the author. If you are trying to learn, you should try to create your own project. Just randomly building code and not understanding the errors you get will not teach you very much.

Comment: im study java of 2 years and on my first job im must build this projetc

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: @Nursultan if it's for your job, find the person who originally wrote it, or who worked on it previously. You don't show us any code, nor an error message. We can't say anything more but: we don't know.

Comment: how may show all code for u?

Comment: @vanje this is full error on cmd

Answer (score 0):

You have shown us an Ant script which invokes the Java compiler to compile some Java code. Ant is reporting that the Java compiler has reported an error in your Java code, and is telling you to look at the compiler error messages for more details.

It's difficult to see what it is about that that you haven't understood.

By the way, this is not an XML question. The "xml" tag is for questions about XML, not for questions about technologies that happen to use XML somewhere in the stack.